# Compile locally and install on remote ros install?

Tags: ros, catkin, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys.

I have a robot running ROS indigo locally on an ARM hf based  Odroid U3.

Would i in any way be able to compile my custom ros packages locally on my laptop and install them to my odroid, through eg. a python script i write myself?
All in order to avoid installing a lot of extra linux packages and keeping the robot in sync with a git repository to compile.

I hope my question makes sense?

Sincerely Mathias

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227723/compile-locally-and-install-on-remote-ros-install?/) by [smilykoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/26095/smilykoch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a similar question about cross-compiling for a BeagleBoard:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/9232/how-to-cross-compile-ros-for-beagleboard-xm-arm/

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0